# Projection of measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

If $ X $ and $ Y $ are metric spaces, $ f: X \rightarrow Y $ is lipschitzian and $ H^k $ is the Haussdorf measure, it is easy to check that $ f(A) $ is $H^k $-measurable whenever $ A $ is $H^k $-measurable. This implies that if

$ p: R^{m+k} \rightarrow R^k $

is the projection onto the first k coordinates then $ p(A) $ is $ L^k $-measurable whenever $ A $ is $ H^k $-measurable, where $ L^k $ is the Lebesgue measure of $ R^k $.

I suspect that it is possible to construct a $ L^2 $-measurable set $ A \subset R^2 $ such that the projection onto the first coordinate is not $ L^1 $-measurable.

Any suggestion for this?
Thank you

Comment: Sure. An easy way is to start with a non-measurable subset $B$ of $\mathbb R$, and let $A=B\times\{0\}$.

Comment: And asking the set to have positive measure does not matter; you can have a circle, and on the side the set $A$. The projection is the disjoint union of an interval and $B$.

Comment: You are right! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Posting the comments as an answer:

Yes, it is possible. An easy way is to start with a non-measurable subset $B$ of $\mathbb R$, and let $A=B\times\{0\}$. This example has measure $0$, but this does not matter: For an example with positive measure, take the union of $A$ and a solid rectangle on the side. The projection is the disjoint union of an interval and the non-measurable set $B$.

On the other hand, if $A$ is "topologically simple", its projection will be measurable: If $A$ is Borel, or analytic (the continuous image of a Borel set), then its projection will be analytic, and all analytic sets are measurable.

Comment: What does it mean topologically simple?

Comment: I just meant analytic, in this case. One could push this a little, and have $A$ instead be a projective set (the complement of an analytic set, or the continuous image of this complement, or the complement of this image, or ...), at the cost of bringing additional set theoretic assumptions into the discussion. I suspect that rather than going that route, one can get significantly more interesting answers closer in spirit to your first paragraph, but I do not have concrete suggestions at the moment.